¿Qué es Flexbox y cómo puedo usarlo?
Estoy comenzando a trabajar en el diseño de sitios web y he escuchado mucho sobre Flexbox. Sin embargo, me resulta un poco confuso entender exactamente qué es Flexbox y cómo puedo usarlo en mis proyectos. Me preguntaba si alguien podría proporcionar una explicación detallada sobre Flexbox y ofrecer algunos ejemplos para ayudarme a comprender cómo implementarlo en mis diseños.
También quisiera saber cuál es la compatibilidad del navegador para Flexbox y cómo puedo asegurarme de que mi diseño sea compatible con los navegadores más antiguos

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Te recomeindo empezar por leer este articulo sobre Flexbox

Este juego puede ayudarte bastante a entender el funcionamiento de flexbox https://flexboxfroggy.com/#es
